# Oracle trunc with timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a timestamp which I want to truncate. I am using the [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) funtion in oracle. This seems to do what I want however from the documentation it should only accept a *date* and not a *timestamp*

```
select TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-13'), 'YEAR') from dual;
select TRUNC(to_timestamp('2013-08-22 06:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YEAR') from dual;
```

Both of the above return the same result.

I presume it works because timestamp is an extension of the date format as quoted [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI16308)

> The TIMESTAMP data type is an extension of the DATE data type. It
>   stores the year, month, and day of the DATE data type, plus the hour,
>   minute, and second values. It has no time zone. The TIMESTAMP data
>   type has the following form:

My question is what is the type of the return value? Is it always the type of the parameter value? Timestamp if parameter is timestamp. Date if parameter is date.

How can I find out the return type?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Oracle reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm

> The TRUNC (*date*) function returns date with the time portion of the
>   day truncated to the unit specified by the format model *fmt*. This
>   function is not sensitive to the NLS_ CALENDAR session parameter. It
>   operates according to the rules of the Gregorian calendar. **The value
>   returned is always of data type DATE, even if you specify a different
>   datetime data type for *date***.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `trunc(timestamp)` function. If you provide a `timestamp` there, an implicit conversion to `date` is done first, and then `trunc(date)` variant is used.

If you want to truncate a `timestamp` without using `date` (because e.g. you want to keep the time zone information), you can subtract the amount you want to truncate:

```
select t-numtodsinterval(mod(extract(second from t),1),'second') trunc_ss
     , t-numtodsinterval(extract(second from t),'second') trunc_mi
     , t-numtodsinterval(60*extract(minute from cast(t as timestamp))+extract(second from t),'second') trunc_hh
     , t-numtodsinterval(3600*extract(hour from cast(t as timestamp))+60*extract(minute from cast(t as timestamp))+extract(second from t),'second') trunc_dd1
     , t-numtodsinterval(3600*extract(hour from t)+60*extract(minute from t)+extract(second from t),'second') trunc_dd2
  from (select timestamp'2000-01-02 03:04:05.678 +03:00' t from dual union all 
        select timestamp'2000-01-02 03:04:05.678 +03:30' t from dual union all 
        select timestamp'2000-01-02 03:04:05.678 +04:00' t from dual)

TRUNC_SS                       TRUNC_MI                       TRUNC_HH                       TRUNC_DD1                      TRUNC_DD2
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
2000-01-02 03:04:05.000 +03:00 2000-01-02 03:04:00.000 +03:00 2000-01-02 03:00:00.000 +03:00 2000-01-02 00:00:00.000 +03:00 2000-01-02 03:00:00.000 +03:00
2000-01-02 03:04:05.000 +03:30 2000-01-02 03:04:00.000 +03:30 2000-01-02 03:00:00.000 +03:30 2000-01-02 00:00:00.000 +03:30 2000-01-01 03:30:00.000 +03:30
2000-01-02 03:04:05.000 +04:00 2000-01-02 03:04:00.000 +04:00 2000-01-02 03:00:00.000 +04:00 2000-01-02 00:00:00.000 +04:00 2000-01-01 04:00:00.000 +04:00
```

The columns are truncated:

- `trunc_ss` – to second,
- `trunc_mi` – to minute,
- `trunc_hh` – to hour,
- `trunc_dd1` – to day,
- `trunc_dd2` – to day in UTC if there is a time zone in the `timestamp`, else the same as `trunc_dd1`.